# Enter key not working in imacros

Tags: imacros

I want my form to submit when I hit the Enter key in the search input control, because the submit button is not available.

When I hit Enter manually it's working properly: the search keyword is submitted successfully. But when I record the successful keypress event using iMacros, it does not do anything during the replay. The event is recorded as `KEY=13`.

The iMacros code I'm using:

```
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>SECTION>ASIDE>DIV>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON" BUTTON=0
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>SECTION>ASIDE>DIV>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>FORM:nth-of-type(2)>TEXTAREA" BUTTON=0
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>SECTION>ASIDE>DIV>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(7)>DIV>FORM:nth-of-type(2)>TEXTAREA" CHARS="2nd search"
EVENT TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="HTML>BODY>DIV>DIV>SECTION>ASIDE>DIV>DIV>UL>LI:nth-of-type(7)" KEY=13
```

Here is the test page of my case: http://zeccartourisme.com/test.html

Comment: It is very hard to tell what you are asking for help with. Try and edit your question to clarify what is working as you want and what is not working and clarify what you want help with.

Comment: when I record macro for doing some keyword search in the website above and press the enter button using my keyboard   the event recorded as KEY=13  and the search keyword submitted successfully 
but when I replay the recorded macro the enter keypress  event do nothing

Comment: @John, I rewrote most of your text hoping to make it more readable. Please check it correctly reflects what you want.

Comment: One idea: add a `WAIT SECONDS=1` before each line in your iMacros script, and see if that improves anything...

Comment: @trincot, I have added a WAIT SECONDS=1 between each line and still not working the problem that it's ignored is the keypress 13 by keyboard enter is working but with event of imacros not working

Comment: If you also put it before the first line, and it still doesn't work, I can't help you further. Maybe someone else can.